# how to write this lines with easiest way, is there a shortcut in keyboard on windows?

Tags: html, css, doctype

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXOPR.png)

how to write this lines with easiest way, is there a shortcut in keyboard on windows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add ! in your html file. Then press enter or tab.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KN7PZ.png

Hope this helps.